# Why aren't my year-old apple seedlings thriving?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, apples, aphids

I planted a variety of seeds from apples from a local orchard. They have been growing for almost a year. They are about 8" and have suffered aphids and a white powdery fungus. I have sprayed plants for both, however I can't seem to get them to come back to life. Some continue to show new growth, yet lost their leaves, others have died. Any advice would be helpful

[image][image]

Comment: These look like all they need is to be planted in the ground - there is evidence of healthy growth in  the centre of each, but they're quite stunted, likely from root restriction - exactly how tall are they?

Comment: I agree with @Bamboo, but they should be dropping their leaves and going dormant for winter by now, so that in itself isn't a problem. Young trees often have more roots than shoots, so if they are 8 inches above ground they might have had 18 inches of roots if they weren't constrained by your pots. Put them in the ground now, with the minimum of root disturbance (plant the whole pot-full of soil) and forget about them till spring. If they don't come back to life then, try again next year!

Comment: What part of  the world are you in?